# Trying to use fit with SelectKBest variable and keep getting a TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use .fit() on my SelectKBest variable and I keep getting an error once my program hits skb.fit(X, y). Not sure why.

Error I'm getting:
**fit % (self.score_func, type(self.score_func)) TypeError: The score function should be a callable, 26.48914983923762 (< class 'numpy.float64' >) was passed.**

My Code:

```
X = df.loc[:, features].astype(float)
y = df.iloc[:, 0].astype(float)

model = LogisticRegression()
classifier = LogisticRegression()
skb = SelectKBest(score_func = chi2, k = 3)

skb.fit(X, y) # Error happens here
```

What my Dataframe looks like:

```
         col1  col2   col3      col4   col5 col6    col7
0           0  22.0   7.2500       3      1  1.0      0
1           1  38.0  71.2833       1      1  0.0      0
2           1  26.0   7.9250       3      0  0.0      0
3           1  35.0  53.1000       1      1  0.0      0
4           0  35.0   8.0500       3      0  1.0      0
..        ...   ...      ...     ...    ...  ...    ...
885         0  39.0  29.1250       3      0  0.0      5
886         0  27.0  13.0000       2      0  1.0      0
887         1  19.0  30.0000       1      0  0.0      0
889         1  26.0  30.0000       1      0  1.0      0
890         0  32.0   7.7500       3      0  1.0      0
```

I tried changing each col to a float

**Edit**: I added a comment on the line where the error happens

Comment: How are you defining chi2? Just importing it?

Comment: And since you're converting your `y` variable to a float while trying to do classification, do you have numbers in `y` that look like `26.48914983923762`?

Comment: chi2 is imported and there aren't any values of `26.48914983923762` in the dataframe. `y` is holds 1s and 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. To fix it by move the import statement further down in the code. The problem is that it is getting confused with an earlier chi2 squared function you called.